# Update Handler AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I want my update Handler in AndEngine to change the colour of the sprite every second (just an example) but the update handler change it only one time and it´s over.

In which of the first 4 methods do I have t initialize the update handler? or why does it run only once?

```
this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(1.0f, new ITimerCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

        z = MathUtils.random(0, 255);
        x = MathUtils.random(0, 255);
        y = MathUtils.random(0, 255);

        sprite.setColor(new Color(x, y, z));
    }
}));
```

Comment: what first four methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourSprite.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(1.0f, true, new ITimerCallback() {

@Override
public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

    z = MathUtils.random(0, 255);
    x = MathUtils.random(0, 255);
    y = MathUtils.random(0, 255);

    sprite.setColor(new Color(x, y, z));
}
}));
```

the second parameter (true) says if it should auto reset and repeat.

Comment: thanks (/.\) as you can see i am a beginner but it really helped me out thanks :)